# PHP || and && logical optimization

Tags: php, performance, optimization, logic

I'm a bit of an optimization freak (at least by my definition) and this question has been bugging me for quite a while.

I'm wondering if PHP does some optimization on && and ||:
Take the following example:

```
$a = "apple";
$b = "orange";
if ($a == "orange" && $b == "orange") {
    //do stuff
}
```

When that code executes, it will check if $a is equal to "orange." In this case it isn't. However, there is an && operator. Since the first part ($a == "orange") already returned false, will PHP still check if $b is equal to "orange?"

I have the same question for ||:

```
$a = "orange";
$b = "orange";
if ($a == "orange" || $b == "orange") {
    //do stuff
}
```

When it checks if $a is equal to "orange," it returns true. Since that would make the || operator return true, will PHP even check the second part of the || (since we already know it will be true)?

Hopefully I am making sense here, and hopefully somebody has an answer for me. Thank you!

Comment: That's what I've always assumed. And, in practice, the AND operator does work that way. For instance, I could do `if (isset($a) && $a instanceof SomeClass && $a->someMethod() == 'orange')` and it has to pass each step of the conditional to test the next. But, I haven't anything to back me up except the fact I just know it works.

Comment: Why not try it? `if (true || die()) { echo '1';}` and `if (true && die()) { echo '1';}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) with binary conditionals (such as `&&`, `||` or their constant equivalents), so if the result of evaluating the LHS means the RHS isn't necessary, it won't.

For example...

```
method_exists($obj, 'func') AND $obj->func();
```

...is an exploitation of this fact. The RHS will only be evaluated if the LHS returns a *truthy* value in this example. The logic makes sense here, as you only want to call a method if it exists (so long as you're not using `__call()`, but that's another story).

You can also use `OR` in a similar fashion.

```
defined('BASE_PATH') OR die('Restricted access to this file.');
```

This pattern is used often as the first line in PHP files which are meant to be included and not accessed directly. If the `BASE_PATH` constant does not exist, the LHS is *falsy* so it executes the RHS, which `die()`s the script.

Comment: Could you perhaps reword that in layman's terms? Haha. I'll do a quick google search on those words.

Comment: @DrAgonmoray after the first condition, PHP will only evaluate additional conditions if necessary :)

Comment: @DrAgonmoray I've added an example, hopefully it is clearer than reading my explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP short-circuits the `&&` and `||` operators, meaning that no, the right operand won't be evaluated if the value of the left operand means that it doesn't need to be evaluated. There's no need to optimize them. You can test it like this:

```
function one() {
    echo "One";
    return false;
}

function two() {
    echo "Two";
    return true;
}

one() && two(); // Outputs One
echo "\n";
two() || one(); // Outputs Two
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/L8SzwXUY) If there were no short-circuiting, you'd get:

```
OneTwo
TwoOne
```

Comment: If important stuff is supposed to happen in function two(), that might never happen, so be careful in limiting the number of lines you write ;)